# Laser Assembler with Hokuyo Utm-30lx

Tags: ros, laser-assembler, hokuyo, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have successfully run the laser_assembler tutorial at:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/laser_assembler/Tutorials/HowToAssembleLaserScans
The tutorial uses a bag file containing the laser data. How can I change the parameters of this tutorial to work with real time hokuyo laser topic that is being published?

Changing parameters in the launch file below does not seem to help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10102/laser-assembler-with-hokuyo-utm-30lx/) by [kp3509](https://answers.ros.org/users/574/kp3509/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2011-05-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shantnu](https://answers.ros.org/users/26813/shantnu/) on 2016-06-08**:
Could you forward that bag file to me if you still have it? Apparently, it has been removed from the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A simple launch file that starts the Hokuyo driver and the assembler would look something like this. First, launch the Hokuyo laser:

```
  <node type="hokuyo_node" pkg="hokuyo_node" name="hokuyo_node/>
```

Verify that you are getting correct laser data. To do that, you can run rviz, add a LaserScan display, and set the fixed frame option to "laser".

The second step is launching the assembler. Both the hokuyo node and the assembler use `scan` as the default topic, so no need to remap.

```
  <node type="laser_scan_assembler" pkg="laser_assembler" name="my_assembler"> 
    <param name="fixed_frame" type="string" value="base_link"/> 
  </node>
```

The last step is to add something that is publishing the correct transform between the `base_link` and the `laser` frames.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2011-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1